# View config 'forceFit' in extjs4?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

In extjs3 Ext.grid.View had a config property `forceFit`.
What is the equivalant to this in extjs4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forceFit` itself! The property has been moved from `View` class to the `Panel`. Refer the [Ext.grid.Pane](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.grid.Panel.html)l documentation.

Rather than using `viewConfig`, you can now directly put it in config of your grid.

Comment: Also, you should realize that the columns are laid out in a hbox layout, so you could simply set each column to flex: 1 to get the same effect.